# How reload particular section in UITableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I tried to reload particular section table view scrolls in top direction automatically and I can't understand what is happening?And I used this below code.When I tap on any button full table view scroll to top direction.

```
        [_moviesDetailTableview beginUpdates];
        [_moviesDetailTableview reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [_moviesDetailTableview endUpdates];
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: @Yuvraj Singh you might be using estimatedRowHeigh which might be different from actual height  for your table this issue generally occurs becoz of that.

Comment: is it happened on ios 8?

Comment: Is your section with index 1 is in visible area? if no, as you are reloading first section, tableview is focusing there...

Comment: @TusharSharma i used estimatedRowHeight

Answer (score 0):

And you can store `content offset` of your tableview. and can do something like,

```
 GPoint contentOffset = _moviesDetailTableview.contentOffset;
 [_moviesDetailTableview beginUpdates];
 [_moviesDetailTableview reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 [_moviesDetailTableview endUpdates];
 [_moviesDetailTableview layoutIfNeeded];
 [_moviesDetailTableview setContentOffset:contentOffset];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
[self.tableView reloadSection:0 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

- (void) reloadSection:(NSInteger)section withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)rowAnimation {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(section, 1);
    NSIndexSet *sectionToReload = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];                                     
    [self reloadSections:sectionToReload withRowAnimation:rowAnimation];
}
```